# `source` command fails in Dockerfile though there are no errors

Tags: bash, docker, shell, ubuntu

I build an image from a Dockerfile that sources a file and builds `ws` workspace with `docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519)" -t my_image .`. But, the build fails on line #4 because cmake complains about some missing packages.
If I comment out lines #3 and #4, build the image and then **manually** do lines #3 and #4 through connecting to the container via `docker exec -it ...` the build of `ws` workspace succeeds. It only tells me that `source` (line #3) fails though there are no errors during docker image build.

What am I missing here? Below is what I have tried.

**Dockerfile**

```
1.  FROM ubuntu:20.04
    ...
2.  WORKDIR /home/ws
    ...  
3.  RUN source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
4.  RUN colcon build
```

**What I tried:**

1. Adding `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` before line #3
2. Changing line #3 to `RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash"]`

Comment: the 2 `RUN` commands run in 2 separate shells so obviously anything that was sourced was lost

Comment: but wouldn't adding `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` before line #3 cause all subsequent commands to be executed in the same shell?

Comment: no. `bash -c somecommand` runs that one command and then exits (anywhere you run bash, not only in docker build); each docker `RUN` line creates a new shell. And `["/bin/bash","-c"]` is the default so setting it explicitly doesn't accomplish anything at all. Do `RUN source /your/file && colcon build` (on a single line) to do it in _one_ shell. (@phuclv)

Comment: You need to execute `source` by the same process which uses the packages established by source. In general, I suggest that instead of having several `RUN` commands, you put everything into a single script and RUN this script. This will also make debugging easier.

Comment: (If you use the standard `.` instead of `source`, you won't need to change `SHELL`.  But it still won't persist beyond a single `RUN` command.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody already told you that each `RUN` execution spawns a separate shell, so the **sourced** script will be lost.

I suggest you to rewrite it as follow:

```
1.  FROM ubuntu:20.04
    ...
2.  WORKDIR /home/ws
    ...  
3.  RUN /bin/bash -c 'source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash; colcon build`
```

Comment: I did this like this `RUN source .../setup.bash && colcon build`

Comment: Ok, it is good too.